# bootstrap column doesn't stack with the image

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to fix this for days....I have an image I inserted on the row.I want the div with the heading and the text to remain positioned the same, when window gets resized for small screens or zooming in.The margin-top property does not help, the content is pushed down.I want it to look like in the image even for small screens. Link: http://www.bootply.com/iLaKEDopmo

[image: picture 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Daniel (or should I say Kylo ;)),

You could achieve that with positioning your text absoutely, but I would also move the image from "img" element to the CSS as background-image.

Here's a little example: 
https://output.jsbin.com/sozumexoyu

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
// css

body {
    background: url("https://s9.postimg.org/fa3rmeei7/Power.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
}
.row {
   margin-top: 60vh;
}
```

and your html like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">   
         <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
             <h1>More power behind every pixel.</h1>
             <p>Lorem ipsum...  </p>
             <p>See the options</p>
         </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Your text will always be positioned in the same place